# Existential type wrappers necessity

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, existential-type, higher-rank-types

Turns out that it is surprisingly difficult to use existential/rank-n types correctly despite the very simple idea behind them.

Why are wrapping existential types into `data` types is necessary?

I have the following simple example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ImpredicativeTypes, ExistentialQuantification #-}
module Main where

c :: Double
c = 3

-- Moving `forall` clause from here to the front of the type tuple does not help,
-- error is the same
lists :: [(Int, forall a. Show a => Int -> a)]
lists = [ (1, \x -> x)
        , (2, \x -> show x)
        , (3, \x -> c^x)
        ]

data HRF = forall a. Show a => HRF (Int -> a)

lists' :: [(Int, HRF)]
lists' = [ (1, HRF $ \x -> x)
         , (2, HRF $ \x -> show x)
         , (3, HRF $ \x -> c^x)
         ]
```

If I comment out the definition of `lists`, the code compiles successfully. If I do not comment it out, I'm getting the following errors:

```
test.hs:8:21:
    Could not deduce (a ~ Int)
    from the context (Show a)
      bound by a type expected by the context: Show a => Int -> a
      at test.hs:8:11-22
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          a type expected by the context: Show a => Int -> a at test.hs:8:11
    In the expression: x
    In the expression: \ x -> x
    In the expression: (1, \ x -> x)

test.hs:9:21:
    Could not deduce (a ~ [Char])
    from the context (Show a)
      bound by a type expected by the context: Show a => Int -> a
      at test.hs:9:11-27
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          a type expected by the context: Show a => Int -> a at test.hs:9:11
    In the return type of a call of `show'
    In the expression: show x
    In the expression: \ x -> show x

test.hs:10:21:
    Could not deduce (a ~ Double)
    from the context (Show a)
      bound by a type expected by the context: Show a => Int -> a
      at test.hs:10:11-24
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          a type expected by the context: Show a => Int -> a at test.hs:10:11
    In the first argument of `(^)', namely `c'
    In the expression: c ^ x
    In the expression: \ x -> c ^ x
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the second example be equivalent to the first one? What is the difference between these usages of n-rank types? Is it possible at all to leave out extra ADT definition and use only simple types when I want such kind of polymorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues you have to consider regarding the handling of existential types:

- If you store "anything that can be `show`n," you have to store the thing that can be shown along with **how to show it**.
- An actual variable can only ever have one single type.

The first point is why you have to have existential type wrappers, because when you write this:

```
data Showable = Show a => Showable a
```

What actually happens is that something like this gets declared:

```
data Showable a = Showable (instance of Show a) a
```

I.e. a reference to the class instance of `Show a` is stored along with the value `a`. Without this happening, you can't have a function that unwraps a `Showable`, because that function wouldn't know how to show the `a`.

The second point is why you get some type quirkiness sometimes, and why you can't bind existential types in `let` bindings, for example.

---

You also have an issue with your reasoning in your code. If you have a function like `forall a . Show a => (Int -> a)` you get a function that, given any integer, will be able to produce any kind of showable value that the **caller chooses**. You probably mean `exists a . Show a => (Int -> a)`, meaning that if the function gets an integer, it will return some type for which there exists a `Show` instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. All answers were immensely helpful, but I think I got "missing pieces of puzzle" from your answer, so I mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Your first attempt is *not* using existential types. Rather your

```
lists :: [(Int, forall a. Show a => Int -> a)]
```

demands that the second components can deliver an element of *any* showable type that I choose, not just *some* showable type that you choose. You're looking for

```
lists :: [(Int, exists a. Show a * (Int -> a))]  -- not real Haskell
```

but that's not what you've said. The datatype packaging method allows you to recover `exists` from `forall` by currying. You have

```
HRF :: forall a. Show a => (Int -> a) -> HRF
```

which means that to build an `HRF` value, you must supply a triple containing a type `a`, a `Show` dictionary for `a` and a function in `Int -> a`. That is, the `HRF` constructor's type effectively curries this non-type

```
HRF :: (exists a. Show a * (Int -> a)) -> HRF   -- not real Haskell
```

You might be able to avoid the datatype method by using rank-n types to Church-encode the existential

```
type HRF = forall x. (forall a. Show a => (Int -> a) -> x) -> x
```

but that's probably overkill.

Answer (score 3):

The examples are not equivalent. The first,

```
lists :: [(Int, forall a. Show a => Int -> a)]
```

says that each second component can produce *any desired type*, as long as it's an instance of `Show` from an `Int`.

The second example is modulo the type wrapper equivalent to

```
lists :: [(Int, exists a. Show a => Int -> a)]
```

i.e., each second component can produce *some* type belonging to `Show` from an `Int`, but you have no idea *which* type that function returns.

Further, the functions you put into the tuples don't satisfy the first contract:

```
lists = [ (1, \x -> x)
        , (2, \x -> show x)
        , (3, \x -> c^x)
        ]
```

`\x -> x` produces the same type as result that it is given as input, so here, that's `Int`. `show` always produces a `String`, so it's one fixed type. finally, `\x -> c^x` produces the same type as `c` has, namely `Double`.